# Verifing all FK in SQL Server 2019 database that exist in other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019-express

I have a table `MyTable` with these columns:

```
MyTableId: int
Results: varchar(200)
```

And I have another table called `Users`:

```
UserId: int
Username: varchar(200)
MyTableId: int
```

I am cleaning up `MyTable` and I have a bunch of results that are now saying 'Bad Data'. I want to get a list of all the MyTableIds that have 'Bad Data' as their result and see if they are any of those Id's in the `User` table.

I am open to any suggestions about this.

A sample data is like so:

```
MyTable
MyTableId (PK)             Results
1                          The quick fox is fast
2                          Bad Data - another piece of very bad data
3                          Humpty dumpty sits on the wall
4                          Hello this is a sample
5                          Bad Data - this data is bad

Users
UserId (PK)           Username                 MyTableId (FK)
1                     User1                    1
2                     User2                    2                     
3                     User3                    3
4                     User4                    1
5                     User5                    5
6                     User6                    2
```

So essentially I need to delete the bad data in MyTable with something like so:

```
DELETEROM MyTable WHERE Results LIKE 'Bad Data%';
```

This won't work because I need a script that deletes the FK data first in the Users table. I need it to be dynamic as this is just sample data.

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempts will help us help you.

Comment: without knowing how you define "bad data" this is going to need sample data.

Comment: Thanks sorry. I have updated the post to show what I really need. It's all the FK constraints causing issues but everything tied to the bad data is garabage from a legacy system that can be deleted.